# Does anyone know of a site that keeps track of monthly Microsoft updates that effect SharePoint?

Tags: cumulative-update, update

It seems that each month after a Microsoft update SharePoint is effected in some way and we have issues, particularly with workflows.  It would be nice to have an comprehensive list somewhere that we could reference to cutback trouble shooting time.

I've been to Microsoft's update page but most of the updates they list are very vague at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rang? :) I have a SharePoint 2013 list at http://www.toddklindt.com/sp2013builds and SharePoint 2010 at http://www.toddklindt.com/sp2010builds. I also maintain two Twitter acccounts, @sp2010patches and @sp2013patches if you want push updates.

tk

Answer (score 8):

I run one at [SharePoint Updates](http://sharepointupdates.com). [Todd Klindt](http://toddklindt.com/sp2013builds) runs another.

Comment: Don't forget Stefan Gossner! :) https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/

Comment: Office 365 road map? http://success.office.com/en-us/roadmap

Comment: My assumption was that this was for on-prem, given there is nothing you can do in SPO with regards to patches.

Comment: As always, thank you to both Trevor and Todd for this service. :)

Comment: O365 roadmap is exceptionally vague.  You're better off with a test (throwaway) tenant in First Release, then running your primary org in Standard Release.